# UPDATE изменение $this->cart->total()

Tags: сессия, codeigniter

Добрый день.
Вопрос состоит в том, как мне изменить общую сумму заказа. 
У меня в магазине будут действовать скидки и в корзине будет поле - "Введите промо код". После ввода - $this->cart->total() должно быть уже меньше на 10%. Как мне это реализовать?
p.s. Codeigniter использую в первый раз...

Answer (score 1):

Например так: `$this->cart->update(array('rowid' => $item['rowid'], 'qty' => $item['qty']));`

Читай внимательно: [Класс Корзины (Shopping Cart)](http://cidocs.ru/210/libraries/cart.html)